# Remove an array element if one of the property contains certain values

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have following variable:

```
var data = [{id: '1', name: 'demo1'}, {id: '2', name: 'demo2'}, {id: '3', name: 'demo3'}]
```

Now I have another list of `id`s,

```
var lookFor = ["2", "3"];
```

Now, from `data` how will I remove the objects with `id` not available in the `lookFor` array of `id`s.

I tried with following

```
_.filter(data, function(item) {
  return _.contains(lookFor, 'id');
});
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Actually, you're not removing any element with `filter` since it creates a new array with the filtered values. Do you really want to **remove** the objects (mutate the array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm consider the following?

```
var data = [{id: '1', name: 'demo1'}, {id: '2', name: 'demo2'}, {id: '3', name: 'demo3'}];
var keys = ["2", "3"];

let filteredArray = data.filter(element => keys.indexOf(element.id) != -1);
console.log(filteredArray);

// Output is now 
// 0: {id: "2", name: "demo2"}
// 1: {id: "3", name: "demo3"}
```

Use this the get the opposite:

```
let filteredArray = data.filter(element => keys.indexOf(element.id) == -1);
console.log(filteredArray);

// Output is:
// 0: {id: "1", name: "demo1"}
```

Is that what you want?

Have a nice day, Elias

Comment: Then you could be so kind and accept it as the answer? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [functor filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for array and method [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to

> determine whether an array includes a certain element

```
 var res =  data.filter(el=>!lookFor.includes(el.id));
```

result

```
 [{id: "1", name: "demo1"}]
```

Opposite

```
var res =  data.filter(el=>lookFor.includes(el.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`_.remove(array, [predicate=_.identity])`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#remove) as following. Notice that this mutates the value of `data`.

```js
var data = [{id: '1', name: 'demo1'}, {id: '2', name: 'demo2'}, {id: '3', name: 'demo3'}];

var lookFor = ["2", "3"];

_.remove(data, function(n) {
  return _.indexOf(lookFor, n.id) === -1;
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are just a few examples of how you can achieve this with ES6 only or with `lodash`. There are obviously more ways to do it but those should give you an idea. Also note that most of the examples `do not` mutate the arrays utilized:

```js
var data = [{id: '1', name: 'demo1'}, {id: '2', name: 'demo2'}, {id: '3', name: 'demo3'}]
var lookFor = ["2", "3"];

// Does not mutate the array and uses ES6 Filter
var withFilter = data.filter(x => lookFor.indexOf(x.id) >= 0)

// Does not mutate the array and uses ES6 Reduce
var withReduce = lookFor.reduce((r,c) => r.push(data.find(x => x.id === c) || []) && r,[])

// Does not mutate the array with Lodah Filter
var withLodashFilter = _.filter(data, x => _.includes(lookFor, x.id))

// Mutates the array with Lodash Remove
var withLodashRemove = _.remove(data, x => _.includes(lookFor, x.id))

console.log('ES6 Filter', withReduce)
console.log('ES6 Reduce', withFilter)
console.log('Lodah Filter', withLodashFilter)
console.log('Lodash Remove', withLodashRemove)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```